# Pivot SQL Table rows to 3 column with sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I tried Pivoting my `SQL` Table but I wasn't able to get the desired result.
My table looks like this

```
DOEntry        RouteID      StoreID        Status
----------------------------------------------------

01-02-2016      100           1134          Complete
01-02-2016      100           419          No Visit
01-02-2016      100           420          Complete
01-02-2016      100           423          Complete
01-02-2016      100           451          Complete
01-02-2016      100           457          Complete
01-02-2016      100           488          Complete
01-02-2016      100           667          Complete
01-02-2016      101           373          Complete
01-02-2016      101          374           Complete
01-02-2016      101          376           Complete
01-02-2016      101          427           Complete
01-02-2016      101          460           Complete
01-02-2016      101          465           Complete
01-02-2016      101          616           No Visit
01-02-2016      101          688           No Visit
02-02-2016      100          421           No Visit
02-02-2016      100          422           No Visit
02-02-2016      100          424           Complete
02-02-2016      100          425           No Visit
02-02-2016      100          456           No Visit
02-02-2016      100          458           Complete
02-02-2016      100          459           Complete
02-02-2016      100          486           Complete
02-02-2016      101          375           Complete
02-02-2016      101          377           Complete
02-02-2016      101          378           Complete
02-02-2016      101          383           No Visit
02-02-2016      101          426           Complete
02-02-2016      101          604           Complete
02-02-2016      101          605           No Visit
02-02-2016      101          609           Complete
```

How do I need the Pivot to Look

```
DOEntry        RouteID      [Complete]        [InComplete]        [No Visit]
01-02-2016      100          7                     0                1
01-02-2016      101          6                     0                2
02-02-2016      100          4                     0                4
02-02-2016      101          6                     0                2
```

`Complete` , `[InComplete]`, `[No Visit]` are the sum found in `StoreID`

FYI: In the given scenario I do understand that you don't see `InComplete` but on a large scale `InComplete` does exist.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that number of values in `STATUS` column is fixed and known. In case if the values are not fixed and unknown in Status you need to use `Dynamic Sql` to do the pivoting

Use `Conditional Aggregate` to do this

```
SELECT DOEntry,
       RouteID,
       [Complete]= Sum(Iif(status = 'Complete', 1, 0)),
       [InComplete]= Sum(Iif(status = 'InComplete', 1, 0)),
       [No Visit]= Sum(Iif(status = 'No Visit', 1, 0))
FROM   Yourtable
GROUP  BY DOEntry,
          RouteID 
Order by DOEntry
```

or You can use `PIVOT` operator

```
SELECT DOEntry,
       RouteID,
       [Complete],
       [InComplete],
       [No Visit]
FROM   Yourtable
       PIVOT (Count(StoreID)
             FOR Status IN ([Complete],
                            [InComplete],
                            [No Visit]))pv
ORDER  BY DOEntry
```

**Result :**

```
╔════════════╦═════════╦══════════╦════════════╦══════════╗
║  DOEntry   ║ RouteID ║ Complete ║ InComplete ║ No Visit ║
╠════════════╬═════════╬══════════╬════════════╬══════════╣
║ 2016-01-02 ║     100 ║        7 ║          0 ║        1 ║
║ 2016-01-02 ║     101 ║        6 ║          0 ║        2 ║
║ 2016-02-02 ║     100 ║        4 ║          0 ║        4 ║
║ 2016-02-02 ║     101 ║        6 ║          0 ║        2 ║
╚════════════╩═════════╩══════════╩════════════╩══════════╝
```

Both will have similar execution plan you can use either of them

**Conditonal Aggregate**

[image: Conditonal Aggregate]

**Pivot**

[image: Pivot]